# Reset html video to start

Tags: javascript, html, video, reset, poster

I have an html video which I need to start from the beginning. I have used

```
video.currentTime = 0;
```

That resets the video to starting place but I have also set poster image for the video. If the video is completely played then poster image shows on the video but when I reset it in the middle, the poster image is not displaying.

```js
$("#splashvideo").get(0).pause();
$('#splashvideo').get(0).currentTime = 0;
```

```html
<video src="Splash.mp4" playsinline width="100%" height="450px" id="splashvideo" muted poster="slideshow_placeholder.png">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

A reload will do the trick

```
$("#slideshowaudio").get(0).load();
```

Comment: I tried that, the video starts from the beginning but still no poster image after load.

Comment: It's a little dirty, but maybe setting `src=""` and then back to the video url

Comment: Still, no poster image for the video.

Comment: If the video is finished then the poster image shows, but not when I stop it in the middle.